# Python error Module has no attribute token

Tags: python, json, pycurl

I am trying to find the tweets using this code but it is resulting a traceback
Please help me to resolve the problem.

```
import time
import pycurl
import urllib
import json
import oauth2 as oauth

API_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json'
USER_AGENT = 'TwitterStream 1.0' # This can be anything really

# You need to replace these with your own values
OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key': 'ABC',
              'consumer_secret': 'ABC',
              'access_token_key': 'ABC',
              'access_token_secret': 'ABC'}

# These values are posted when setting up the connection
POST_PARAMS = {'include_entities': 0,
               'stall_warning': 'true',
               'track': 'iphone,ipad,ipod'}

# twitter streaming is here    

class TwitterStream:
    def __init__(self, timeout=False):
        self.oauth_token = oauth.Token(key=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_key'], secret=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_secret'])
        self.oauth_consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], secret=OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
        self.conn = None
        self.buffer = ''
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.setup_connection()

    def setup_connection(self):
        """ Create persistant HTTP connection to Streaming API endpoint using cURL.
        """
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.close()
            self.buffer = ''
        self.conn = pycurl.Curl()
        # Restart connection if less than 1 byte/s is received during "timeout" seconds
        if isinstance(self.timeout, int):
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1)
            self.conn.setopt(pycurl.LOW_SPEED_TIME, self.timeout)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, API_ENDPOINT_URL)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, USER_AGENT)
        # Using gzip is optional but saves us bandwidth.
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.ENCODING, 'deflate, gzip')
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, urllib.urlencode(POST_PARAMS))
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Host: stream.twitter.com',
                                             'Authorization: %s' % self.get_oauth_header()])
        # self.handle_tweet is the method that are called when new tweets arrive
        self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.handle_tweet)

    def get_oauth_header(self):
        """ Create and return OAuth header.
        """
        params = {'oauth_version': '1.0',
                  'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
                  'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time())}
        req = oauth.Request(method='POST', parameters=params, url='%s?%s' % (API_ENDPOINT_URL,
                                                                             urllib.urlencode(POST_PARAMS)))
        req.sign_request(oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1(), self.oauth_consumer, self.oauth_token)
        return req.to_header()['Authorization'].encode('utf-8')

    def start(self):
        """ Start listening to Streaming endpoint.
        Handle exceptions according to Twitter's recommendations.
        """
        backoff_network_error = 0.25
        backoff_http_error = 5
        backoff_rate_limit = 60
        while True:
            self.setup_connection()
            try:
                self.conn.perform()
            except:
                # Network error, use linear back off up to 16 seconds
                print 'Network error: %s' % self.conn.errstr()
                print 'Waiting %s seconds before trying again' % backoff_network_error
                time.sleep(backoff_network_error)
                backoff_network_error = min(backoff_network_error + 1, 16)
                continue
            # HTTP Error
            sc = self.conn.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
            if sc == 420:
                # Rate limit, use exponential back off starting with 1 minute and double each attempt
                print 'Rate limit, waiting %s seconds' % backoff_rate_limit
                time.sleep(backoff_rate_limit)
                backoff_rate_limit *= 2
            else:
                # HTTP error, use exponential back off up to 320 seconds
                print 'HTTP error %s, %s' % (sc, self.conn.errstr())
                print 'Waiting %s seconds' % backoff_http_error
                time.sleep(backoff_http_error)
                backoff_http_error = min(backoff_http_error * 2, 320)

    def handle_tweet(self, data):
        """ This method is called when data is received through Streaming endpoint.
        """
        self.buffer += data
        if data.endswith('\r\n') and self.buffer.strip():
            # complete message received
            message = json.loads(self.buffer)
            self.buffer = ''
            msg = ''
            if message.get('limit'):
                print 'Rate limiting caused us to miss %s tweets' % (message['limit'].get('track'))
            elif message.get('disconnect'):
                raise Exception('Got disconnect: %s' % message['disconnect'].get('reason'))
            elif message.get('warning'):
                print 'Got warning: %s' % message['warning'].get('message')
            else:
                print 'Got tweet with text: %s' % message.get('text')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ts = TwitterStream()
    ts.setup_connection()
    ts.start()
```

Traceback call:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\nytimes\2062014\pycurltweets.py", line 115, in <module>
    ts = TwitterStream()
  File "C:\Python27\nytimes\2062014\pycurltweets.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.oauth_token = oauth.token(key=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_key'], secret=OAUTH_KEYS['access_token_secret'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Token'
```

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say that `token` in `oauth.token` was supposed to be capitalized, and that the last line actually said `'token'` instead of `'Token'` in the traceback.

Comment: That has happened during editing. In both cases it is showing same error

Comment: Please test the exact version of the code you post, and post the exact traceback that version of the code produces. If you mess with your error messages, you make it very hard for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience. you can consider any of the case either lowercase token or uppercase Token. It is reverting the same error 'module' object has no attribute 'token' or 'Token'.

Comment: Do you have a local file called oauth2.py, by any chance?

Comment: yes there was an egg file by the same name I have renamed it oauth2help.py now but still getting the same traceback Daniel

Comment: Thanks guys for your support. I rectified the problem. but Now I am getting the HTTP error 401. help me out if anyone has any idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure oauth2 is installed properly /  is the correct version?

see http://data-scientist.ch/install-oauth2-for-python-on-windows/

open a python REPL shell and

```
import oauth2 as oauth
print oauth.OAUTH_VERSION
dir(oauth)
```

and post result

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/nytimes/2062014/aiwehetest.py", line 2, in <module>
    print oauth.OAUTH_VERSION
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OAUTH_VERSION'

Comment: this is reverting the error  traceback mentioned above

Comment: uninstall and reinstall your oauth version; make sure correct version of oauth is in your settings..

Comment: Wingston I am new to python. please guide me to uninstall it & reinstall.